# Create ipa file with enterprise deployment in iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipa

I am using Xcode 7.2 with iOS 9.2. I want to create IPA file with enterprise deployment.I am using **development provisioning** profile for archiving the application.I used the following procedure for this purpose 
I choose **Product-> Archive** option .Then i got archive file in my organizer. From here i select **export** option for corresponding file.After this i choose **Save for enterprise deployment** and also select development team for provisioning profile.After i got the following error shows like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See either you should  **Try upgrading your role to Team Admin** at [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com).

or

event if the issue still remain **you can try to export IPA using Terminal command**

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $projectname.xcarchive -exportPath $yourprojectname -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile "Your Provisioning Profile Name"
```

Comment: Now i have access only to Team member.Is any problem to use development provisional certificate?

Comment: If you do not have admin privileges, Xcode may through an issue while exporting IPA. event same works on other stable XCode versions.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1371853/rdc.  Can you come to this room..I have one doubt.Please

Answer (score 0):

In enterprise distibution create certificate for in-House

[image]

and publish with this certificate